# Apache Quickstart not working: "The defined artifact is not an archetype"

Tags: maven, apache-flink

I'm trying to get started with the basic Flink quickstart examples.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html

I'm getting an error at the very first step with Maven. Regardless of whether I try to install using Maven or the "curl" command, I get the same error "The defined artifact is not an archetype":

Command:

```
mvn archetype:generate                               \
>       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink              \
>       -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java      \
>       -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0
```

Response:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.apache.flink:flink-quickstart-java:1.2.1] found in catalog remote
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.916 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-03T18:16:55+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/280M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The defined artifact is not an archetype -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I'm very confused as I was able to execute these quickstarts last week without problem, and I'm completely new to Maven/Flink so I'm having trouble pinpointing what could have changed since then. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed something in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file?

Comment: Nope, tried with a fresh install of maven on two different computers and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Only defining the archetype is not enough. You also need to provide details for the current maven project itself.

- Either you have to pass the 'groupId', 'artifactId' and 'version' in the interactive mode when you run the above mentioned command.
- Or, you can use the following command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0 -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=flink -Dversion=0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with a similar error while I was trying to generate the "graphwalker" archetype using below command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.graphwalker \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=graphwalker-maven-archetype \
-DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=myProject \
-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

However, my clue was I could generate it in the first time, but the second time it threw a similar error.

I was able to solve it by removing ./m2/repository and generating the archetype again.

```
rm -rf ./m2/repository
```